# Is there a way to set alpha channel color for sampler2D texture?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I am working on an app that uses OpenGL-ES to blend two textures. For overlay image, I want to specify a certain color as the alpha channel e.g.) green. How could this be accomplished? I tried using glBlendFunc without much success. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

there is no such feature in OpenGL itself, but maybe you could achieve that in shader:

```
uniform vec3 colorMask; // eg. green

varying vec2 texCoord;
uniform sampler2D overlay;

void main()
{
    vec4 texture = texture2D(overlay, texCoord);
    // get RGB of the texture

    vec3 absdiff = abs(texture.rgb - colorMask);
    float alpha = all(lessThan(absdiff, vec3(0.1)))? 1.0 : 0.0;
    // calculate alpha using vector relational functions

    texture.a = alpha; // use alpha

    gl_FragColor = texture;
    // write final color, can use blending
}
```

This works by calculating absolute difference of texture color and masking color, and comparing it to 0.1. It is pretty simple, but it might be slow (i'm writing it from memory, you have to test it).

Or you can use a different way of calculating alpha:

```
uniform vec3 colorMask; // eg. green

varying vec2 texCoord;
uniform sampler2D overlay;

void main()
{
    vec4 texture = texture2D(overlay, texCoord);
    // get RGB of the texture

    vec3 diff = texture.rgb - colorMask;
    float alpha = step(dot(diff, diff), 0.1);
    // calculate alpha using difference squared and a step function

    texture.a = alpha; // use alpha

    gl_FragColor = texture;
    // write final color, can use blending
}
```

This is using the square error metric to calculate alpha. It calculates distance of colors in RGB space, calculates it's square, and compares that to 0.1. This might be a little bit harder to tweak the threshold (0.1) but enables you to use soft threshold. If you were to have color gradient and wanted some colors to be more transparent than other, you can throw away step function and use smoothstep instead.